# R G B to one image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I currently have an image, im as an  array of dimensions 600*800*3. The last dimension is for color, but if i do imshow(im) I see black. How do I add the R G and B of the image. I have used the following code, but I need confirmation or if there is any better way. As I see something now, but it is like shadows. The code used is below:

```
imdata = im1;
RC = imdata(:,:,1);
GC = imdata(:,:,2);
BC = imdata(:,:,3);
FC = RC + GC + BC;
imshow(FC)
```

FC has dimensions 600*800. Is this the right way, or is there any other way? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I have added the scaling factor as follows:

```
FC = 33RC + 33GC + 33BC;
```

The image I see is greyscale, and much brighter. So is it right?

Edit2: I have used the following factor as mentioned in comments:

```
rgb = 0.2989 * RC + 0.5870 * GC + 0.1140 * BC;
rgb = uint8(255*rgb);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20959617/2777181

Comment: When you say 'I see black' do you mean that it shows an image that looks like grayscale? or nothing is displayed?

Comment: Does `imshow(im, [])` show the original image correctly?

Comment: Nope. So it shows black with 2 white spots. Which I think need brightness to see the figure. As such right now there is no figure to be seen at all.

Comment: How convinced are you that your image is not black with two white spots? Have you tried using `imshow(im); imcontrast` and adjust the window manually?

Comment: Yes it is an apple with 3 white balls. When I scale using the method I mentioned in the question, that is what I see.

Comment: So, by multiplying each channel by large values (e.g. 33) the image becomes useful. Then I'd suggest multiplying `im1` by 65535 and converting to `uint8`, then it might be color. The reason is because for `double`s, display functions expect [0,1], but for `uint8`, it expects [0,255].

Comment: It works for certain images and does not work for others. It will show a plain white background with the white dots reversed to black dots. Any ideas why that might be happening? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal weighting is actually *not* the way to perform RGB -> grayscale conversion.  There is a weighting vector used by [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html) that is based on human visual perception of colors. It uses the following code to compute the weighting:

```
T    = inv([1.0 0.956 0.621; 1.0 -0.272 -0.647; 1.0 -1.106 1.703]);
coef = T(1,:)
```

This comes out to

```
0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
```

as the proper weighting for RGB planes. See the [Algorithms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html#f6-84521) part of the `rgb2gray` documentation. Also reference the NTSC [luminance computations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to.2Ffrom_RGB).

Anyway, use `rgb2gray`:

```
imGray = rgb2gray(im1);
```

Or if you do not have the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
FC = 0.2989 * imdata(:,:,1) + 0.5870 * imdata(:,:,2) + 0.1140 * imdata(:,:,3)
```

But don't forget to perform the conversion in floating point and convert back to integer (`imdata = double(im1);` then `FC = uint8(FC);`.

**EDIT**: If your input data (`im1`) was already scaled on `[0,1]`, then you need to multiply by 255 before converting to `uint8` (`FC = uint8(255*FC);`).

**EDIT 2**: If you just want to see your original color image and it displays as black, then perhaps it is the wrong data type or scaled incorrectly for the data type.

Comment: I'm not convinced that OP is trying to convert a RGB image into grayscale, it sound more to me that he/she has a grayscale image in RGB format and is confused about it.

Comment: @Jigg It's unclear, but OP says: "Edit: I have added the scaling factor as follows: `FC = 33RC + 33GC + 33BC;` The image I see is greyscale, and much brighter. So is it right?" My answer is "No, not quite. Here's the correct way."

Comment: @chappjc Thanks for your response. So I tried your way, but I still see black, with 2 white spots. But I see no shape at all. I scaled the FC by multiplying it with 255 as well. Any ideas what might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend `im2uint8` over converting manually - just for simplicity and robustness - given that the OP has `imshow` which implies IPT. Of course, that still assumes the original data is scaled correctly for whatever type it is, which doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: @student001 Do `hist(im1(:))` and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I get a block: y-axis: 14, x-axis: 0.1 
Hope it helps somehow!

Comment: @student001 There's just one bar? if the x axis maxes out at `0.1`, then your data is definitely scaled badly regardless of the datatype. I don't know why. If `im1` is a `double` (check with whos), and it seems to be, you can at least get an image to display by scaling by the max (`im1 = uint8(255 * im1/max(im1(:)));`) or try `im2uint8` as @Notlikethat suggested.

Comment: Hello, it is a rectangle spanning from 0 to 0.1. Does that sound good?