# access and change the values of the R, G and B of a desired pixel in an image using MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

How can I change the values of the R, G and B in an image manually using MATLAB?

The computation for a green color enhancement needs to be done so how do we access and change the values of RGB using MATLAB?

Comment: How are you creating the image? What methods have you tried and why didn't they work? If you give some code that reproduces the problem, then someone may be able to help.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20959617/2777181

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `imread` to read in the image, an RGB image is stored as an `M x N x 3` matrix, where `M,N` are the rows and columns of the image.  This is essentially a 3D matrix, where each colour plane is in a particular dimension.  The red plane is the first of the third dimensions, the green plane is the second, and the blue plane is the third.  As such, you can do something like:

```
im = imread('onion.png'); % // Built-in to MATLAB
red = im(:,:,1); %// Red channel
green = im(:,:,2); % // Green channel
blue = im(:,:,3); % // Blue channel
```

You can also merge the planes back by doing: `im2 = cat(3, red, green, blue);`  Now, you can manipulate any of these planes by themselves.  If you want to grab a subset of the image, you can do:

```
imSubset = im(row1:row2, col1:col2, :);
```

This will grab all pixels between rows `row1` to `row2` and columns `col1` to `col2`.  You can then split up the image into their corresponding planes.

Now, if you want to *manually* change pixels, you simply access whichever rows and columns you want in each of the planes and set them to whatever you want.  For example, if you wanted to set a particular region in your image to all yellow pixels, you can do this:

```
im(1:50,1:50,1) = 0;
im(1:50,1:50,2) = 255;
im(1:50,1:50,3) = 255;
imshow(im);
```

This should place a yellow square of 50 pixels wide in the top left corner.  You can also do the subset approach by:

```
imSubset = im(1:50,1:50,:); %// Extract
imSubset(:,:,1) = 0; %// Set
imSubset(:,:,2) = 255;
imSubset(:,:,3) = 255;
im(1:50,1:50,:) = imSubset; %// Place back
```

If I can be a shameless promoter, take a look at my Introduction to Digital Image Processing using MATLAB slides - http://www.slideshare.net/rayryeng1/introduction-to-digital-image-processing-using-matlab

Good luck!

Comment: @user3697940 you're welcome.  If you feel that this has helped you, please consider accepting my answer.  Click on the checkmark below the up and down arrows at the top to the left near my post.